# Перемещение логотипа с анимацией

Tags: javascript, css, анимация, hmtl

На этом сайте jolybell.com очень хорошая анимация логотипа, когда логотип уходит в левый верхний угол при маленьком экране. Можете как то подсказать как оно делается? Я смог сделать только тот сценарий который производиться там с большими экранами когда логотип уходить строго вверх, а мне надо сделать чтобы лого уезжало лево вверх. Буду рад ответам

Comment: Если вы хотите чтобы вам помогли, не ленитесь предоставить ваш код